# Jmeter wrapper class when a json with int value is added in the preprocessor

Tags: jmeter

I am adding a preprocessor using JSR223preprocessor. This creates a JSON object and get base64 of that JSON string, which is sent in the post request of the body along with other json elements.
when I  run the script in mac using jmeter5.3 I don't get any error using command mode and GUI, but when the same script is copied to an ubuntu machine that has the same version JMeter 5.3 I get a wrapper class error.
below is a snippet of the code
I used setStrictJava (true);

```
JsonArray Events = new JsonArray();
JsonArray phoneLocation = new JsonArray();
JsonArray anomalies = new JsonArray();
JsonObject MetaData= new JsonObject();
JsonObject ano= new JsonObject();
JsonObject pl = new JsonObject();
metaData.addProperty("activity","FOOT");
metaData.addProperty("id",UUID.randomUUID().toString()); 
metaData.addProperty("frequency",100);
metaData.add("phone_location",phoneLocation);
metaData.add("Events",Events);
```

error i received from the log in ubuntu machine is internal Error: error in wrapper cast : at Line: 27 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``import com.google.gson.JsonArray; import com.google.gson.JsonObject; import com. . . . '' : MetaData.addProperty ( "frequency" , 100 ). when I change it to a string it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into your [`setStringJava` function](http://beanshell.org/manual/strictjava.html) call it seems that you're still using Beanshell however [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), so if you:

1. Switch the "Language" to `groovy`
2. Remove this `setStrictJava` function call

your code should start working as expected (given you have this "gson" library in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)) on another machine

Also with Groovy you don't need any extra libraries to work with JSON as [Groovy supports parsing and producing JSON out of the box](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: I did select java bean shell  in JSR223 processor.I do have gson library in the jmeter class path